# (HTTP-)Connecting Hyper-V VM to Host

Tags: hyper-v

to solve a webdesign issue with an old version of Internet Explorer, I downloaded a Hyper-V image from Microsoft (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) and started this with the Hyper-V Manager.

In the Hyper-V Manager I created an "internal" network switch, and selected that switch for the VM's network connection. I set an IPv4 address (192.168.1.1) on my Host for this network, and another address (192.168.1.2) on the VM for the network.

Now, I'm stuck: I cannot ping from the Host to the VM or the other way around (each computer can ping it's own network address). What am I missing? I read some tutorials about Hyper-V networks, but can't find the point...

I had also tried the "external" switch, which allowed the VM to connect to the Internet - but again not to the Host, although the IP addresses (then automatically retrieved) are in the same subnet.

Thanks for advice and hints!

Comment: Ping isn't enabled by default in Windows and you shouldn't be using it unless you know it should work, which it doesn't by default. Why are you so concerned with the Host and VM being able to communicate with each other? That isn't related to anything.

Comment: I do not want to use the VM in a productive way, but just to run the IE. The host is my development machine for a web application. It runs a local web server to test the application. Usually the local browser connects to the local "web server" via 127.0.0.1 or the local IP (192.168.1.1 works as well, now the virtual switch is active). Now, I need to test it in IE10 - so the VM with its IE10 requires HTTP access to the host.

Comment: Okay ... I found another solution for the problem: Using an "external" switch (do not check the identify... option there), run the webserver on another computer in the LAN, and then address this computer's IP address. This did not actually answer the question, but let me so the work.